# Selenium fails with empty exception message

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm using Selenium 2.7.0 and Python 2.6, my OS is Mac OS X 10.7.
When I'm trying to instantiate webdriver  object I'm getting the following message:

```
selenium.common.exception.WebDriverException: Message: ''
```

Previously I was using Selenium 2.13.0, but I've installed older version because I have working installation on another machine. The first attempt (after reinstallation) to launch webdriver was successful, but all subsequent are not. Then I tried to use Chrome driver instead Firefox, and got the same situation: successful first attempt and unsuccessful subsequent ones.
It's quite hard to google because error message is empty.

Comment: What is the version of Firefox? Selenium 2.7.0. supported only up to Firefox 7 (and that without native events). Can you reproduce the same behaviour with Selenium 2.20.0?