# Empty error message in Selenium WebDriverException

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to use Selenium/BeautifulSoup to unit test a web page. I am getting an error though that I haven't been able to Google.

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: ''`

I am using a Portable version of Firefox and a proxy.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
import sys

def getItemDivs(url):
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0")
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", "proxy.example.com")

    ffbin = webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary.FirefoxBinary('C:\\FirefoxPortable\\App\\Firefox\\firefox.exe')

    # IT FAILS ON THE NEXT LINE
    driver=webdriver.Firefox(profile, firefox_binary=ffbin)
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)

    # THIS LINE CONTAINS A VALID COOKIE, BUT IT HAS BEEN REMOVED FOR THIS QUESTION.
    driver.add_cookie(<<mycookie>>)
    base_url = url
    verificationErrors = []
    accept_next_alert = True

    driver.get(base_url)
    scrap1 = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(scrap1)
```

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470193/selenium-fails-with-empty-exception-message), however, in that question they had a successful first request. I haven't had a success.

What can cause this type of exception but leave the message empty?

Comment: thanks for "ffbin = webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary.FirefoxBinary('C:\\FirefoxPortable\\App\\Firefox\\firefox.exe')

    # IT FAILS ON THE NEXT LINE
    driver=webdriver.Firefox(profile, firefox_binary=ffbin)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't set the `network.proxy.port`. Adding this line solved the problem:

```
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.port", "80")
```