# Python code works locally but not on server (Discord bot with selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

My code takes user input and uses it to search for an item on a webpage. it scrapes the html code of the webpage in order to get the items that appeared as a result:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(urlItem)
#this last line is the one that's not working on heroku
item_list = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('price-history-link')
```

this is the html code:

```
<ul class="no-padding small-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-5 text-center word-wrap-break-word">
<li>
<a href="/item/7399/"><img src="/assets/imgs/items/7399.gif" alt="A Grey Faerie Doll" title="A Grey Faerie Doll" class="item-result-image"></a><br><a href="/item/7399/">A Grey Faerie Doll</a>
<br><span class="text-small"><a href="/item/7399/price-history/" class="price-history-link" title="October 31, 2019">2,400,000 NP</a></span>
</li>
</ul>
```

When I run the code locally, the bot works perfectly. When I run the exact same code from my hosting site (heroku), it doesn't return any items.
I thought that maybe it was a loading issue, so I added a :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "price-history-link")))
```

when this code is in place, it returns an exception (only when run on the hosting site, it works perfectly when run on my pc)

> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

yes, the exception ends there, it doesnt actually show me the message.

I really don't understand why it won't work on heroku...
any help is very appreciated!

Edit: Put in a catch for a NoSuchElementException, but it didn't catch anything

Comment: Have a look at the potential duplicate, it sounds scarily similar to your issue!

Comment: Check if you have any CORS errors in your console

Comment: Alternatively this: `What is the version of Firefox? Selenium 2.7.0. supported only up to Firefox 7 (and that without native events). Can you reproduce the same behaviour with Selenium 2.20.0?` [Empty Error Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470193/selenium-fails-with-empty-exception-message) and [Empty Error Message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56773496/11700321)

Comment: im using chromedriver not firefox

Answer (score 0):

You saw it right. `WebDriverWait()` in conjunction with `expected_conditions()` will always return **`TimeoutException`** on failure.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Random Selenium E2e Tests Fail because of timeouts on Azure DevOps but work locally and with remote Selenium (BrowserStack Automate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53190909/random-selenium-e2e-tests-fail-because-of-timeouts-on-azure-devops-but-work-loca/53391005#53391005)

---

### This usecase

As you are using the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) `CLASS_NAME` as **`price-history-link`** possibly this CLASS_NAME is associated with some hidden elements as well. Hence, when you use `find_elements_by_class_name()`, elements are identified where as `visibility_of_element_located()` results into `TimeoutException`.

---

### Solution

To simulate `find_elements_by_class_name()` along with `WebDriverWait()` and in conjunction with `expected_conditions()` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  item_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.price-history-link[href$='/price-history/'][title*='20']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  item_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='price-history-link' and contains(@href, '/price-history/')][contains(., 'NP')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! Sadly it didnt work. This bot searches for an item, and checks the results and returns them, apparently the searches are coming up empty for some reason. my theory is that my hosting site is blocking the page from showing the results

Comment: @SouthRescuer _...bot searches for an item..._ would be easy as search boxes are generally within the Top Window where as the **search results** can be within an _iframe_. So traverse up the DOM and check if the results are within an _iframe_.